# Should I use Timer, ThreadPool, AutoResetEvent , or "join" with Impersonation?

Tags: c#, timer, impersonation, sleep, threadpool

After reading SO extensively, I understand that `Thread.Sleep` is [a bad idea](http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program.aspx).  Instead, the general consensus is that server-side tasks should use a `Timer`, a `threadpool`, or maybe use a `Join()`.

One [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391621/compare-using-thread-sleep-and-timer-for-delayed-execution) mentions difficulties in disposing the timer.

Another [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822441/system-timers-timer-threading-timer-vs-thread-with-whileloop-thread-sleep-for-p/2822506#2822506) mentions using `waitOne`

**Question**

What is the right approach to use when launching a long running task that will repeat every 30 seconds, 1 minute, or 5 minutes?  The constraint is that IF the previous run of that task is longer than the interval (32 seconds, or 7 minutes) then I want the option to either kill that previous instance, or not execute a new instance.

A potential gotcha is that I intend to use impersonation on these threads using either [WindowsImpersionationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext.aspx), P/Invoke[LogonUserEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378189(VS.85).aspx), or [DCOMShim](http://dcomshim.codeplex.com/) as needed.

I'm not sure what approach to take, and why.

**Possible Answer 1**

This example appears to be straightforward, with minimal code clutter

```
    // initially set to a "non-signaled" state, ie will block
    // if inspected
   private readonly AutoResetEvent _isStopping = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    /// <summary>
    /// from...
    /// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822441/system-timers-timer-threading-timer-vs-thread-with-whileloop-thread-sleep-for-p/2822506#2822506
    /// </summary>
    public void SampleDelay1()
    {
        TimeSpan waitInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);

        // will block for 'waitInterval', unless another thread,
        // say a thread requesting termination, wakes you up. if
        // no one signals you, WaitOne returns false, otherwise
        // if someone signals WaitOne returns true
        for (; !_isStopping.WaitOne(waitInterval); )
        {
            // do your thang!
        }
    }
```

**Possible Answer 2**

This example offers similar functionality, but uses anonymous types that may not be permitted in companies that don't allow for that in their coding standard.

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Disposable Timer instance from 
    /// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391621/compare-using-thread-sleep-and-timer-for-delayed-execution
    /// </summary>
    class TimerStackOverFlow
    {
   // Created by Roy Feintuch 2009
        // Basically we wrap a timer object in order to send itself as a context in order
        // to dispose it after the cb invocation finished. This solves the problem of timer 
        // being GCed because going out of context
        public static void DoOneTime(ThreadStart cb, TimeSpan dueTime)
        {
            var td = new TimerDisposer();
            // Is the next object System.Timers, or System.Threading
            var timer = new Timer(myTdToKill =>
            {
                try
                {
                    cb();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("[DoOneTime] Error occured while invoking delegate. {0}", ex), "[OneTimer]");
                }
                finally
                {
                    ((TimerDisposer)myTdToKill).InternalTimer.Dispose();
                }
            },
                        td, dueTime, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1));

            td.InternalTimer = timer;
        }
    }

    class TimerDisposer
    {
        public Timer InternalTimer { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used your first approach many times, and it works well.

The second solution appears to be a generic encapsulation of a time-based trigger for a one-time event. If you're looking at recurring events, then this approach seems unnecessarily complicated to me with no obvious benefit gained from the added complexity.

Comment: Thanks, I just updated the question with a potential gotcha... Impersonation.