# Can't match times in C#

Tags: c#

I've got a very simple program written in C#, but the loop never exits because the times don't match.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (System.DateTime.Now != new System.DateTime(2011, 05, 23, 22, 17, 0))
    {
    }
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(file);   
}
```

The idea is that when the time ticks over to the specified time, then the given file will be started. However, I've tested this program with values which are, for example, just one minute ahead of the current time as reported by Windows, and it won't start the process. I've verified that the `Process.Start` call is correct. Any suggestions?

Edit: No, this is not an experiment or anything of the sort. It's because I keep turning off my alarm clocks in my sleep. `file` is an mp3 file, and I'm going to leave my speakers on, and I'm pretty sure that I don't possess the capacity to deal with that in my sleep. First ever practical problem I solved with a program. As it possesses a rather specific purpose, I think you'll agree that the necessity of another solution is, well, limited.

Edit: I didn't realize that the DateTime type went down to that kind of precision, else I would have spotted this myself. I thought that they were only valid down to the second, and since the loop should run even in debug mode in the IDE many, many times a second, I didn't see why an exact match would be unreasonable. But, of course, if you're comparing it down to the hundred nanoseconds, it's pretty damn unlikely.

Comment: @DeadMG: Considering that can be done in ~8 lines of C++ code, total, I'm wondering why you chose to do it in C# if not as an experiment.

Comment: It will only exist for one millisecond (or whatever mesure the dateTime use).

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I don't believe that I have any C++ libraries that would perform such a task at hand, whereas I know for a fact that .NET does provide.

Comment: @DeadMG: `CreateWaitableTimer`, `SetWaitableTimer`, `WaitForSingleObject`, `ShellExecute`.  All core Win32 API functions.

Comment: The accuracy of the clock is actually about 1/64th of a second. Which is plenty big enough to miss since that's about the thread quantum; some other thread could be running for that 1/64th of a second.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: SetWaitableTimer doesn't take a time and date, it takes a number of 100ns intervals after which to activate. If I wanted to use it, I'd have to compute that value. And I couldn't get the file to open with ShellExecute- actually tried that before Process.Start.

Comment: @DeadMG: `SystemTimeToFileTime` to convert a date (year/month/day style) to the format used by `SetWaitableTimer`.  We may now be needing more than 8 lines of C++.  And I find it surprising that `ShellExecute` didn't work, since that's what the static `Process.Start` method uses.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Yeah, me too. Could be that I just messed up the file and directory parameters, but it doesn't really matter. And I have definitely never seen SystemTimeToFileTime before, else I think I would have gone to C++ for this.

Comment: @DeadMG: If you're still on the fence, let me point out also that `SetWaitableTimer` can resume a system from ACPI sleep at the specified time.

Comment: I would expect anyone who is looking for an alarm clock MP3 player to immediately try Window's Task Scheduler. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (System.DateTime.Now < new System.DateTime(2011, 05, 23, 22, 17, 0))
    {
    }
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(file);   
}
```

Since if you don't tick on that exact time it isn't going to ever exit the while

**Edit** long explanation of why != most likely won't work
So actually you could write the code like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DateTime fireDate = new DateTime(2011, 05, 23, 22, 17, 0);

    while (System.DateTime.Now < fireDate)
    {
    }
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(file);   
}
```

As Ben Voigt pointed out `DateTime` comparisons looks at the `Ticks` property on a `DateTime` [DateTime.Ticks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) which is `1/10,000` of a millisecond.

Your loop probably doesn't execute that frequently.

Comment: This was the correct answer. I would have expected that the tick rate of the loop would be vastly in excess of what would be required to hit the match, but this works too.

Comment: @DeadMG I gave some more insight on why an exact match won't work for you.

Comment: @msarchet: No, millisecond isn't the lowest resolution of DateTick, and `operator !=` doesn't use it.  It directly compares the `InternalTicks` field (source of the [`Ticks` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks)), ticks are 10,000 times smaller than a millisecond.

Comment: @Ben Voigt ah, I just quickly looked at DateTime. adjusting my answer to reflect your added knowledge.

Comment: Nitpick: This is creating a Spinlock, which is a very bad way of doing things. A better way would be a Thread.Sleep. But you pointed out the proper problem: Test for greater-than instead of equality.

Answer (score 3):

Why wouldn't you just use a sleep or create a timer?

Comment: Answer vs comment aside (especially given that he only just barely can comment now at 50), this is the more efficient solution. A test app shows the loop holding 25% CPU until it breaks, while using a System.Threading.Timer sits at 0% CPU. See also this post about using "more robust Timer mecahnisms in .NET." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822441/system-timers-timer-threading-timer-vs-thread-with-whileloop-thread-sleep-for-p

Comment: @druttka: I have no need to not block the CPU, as it's part of the use case of the application that I will not be using the machine whilst it's running. Also, I have an i7 and even if I lost a core whilst trying to use it, it would hardly degrade my experience.

Comment: @DeadMG That's fine for you in this case. My comment is for any others who may come along later and want their application to perform while the user is awake :)

Comment: @druttka: don't forget that heating up a core like that has big costs. In rack-mounted hardware most of the cost of the machine is actually air conditioning, and on laptops, the last thing you want is a core devoted to doing nothing but draining the battery as fast as possible. Maybe you don't care about these scenarios but I assure you many people do. There are better ways to wait for something than busy waiting in a tight loop.

Comment: @Eric Thanks, battery drain and heat are excellent points. I hope my previous comment expressed it, but I do support this answer rather than the tight loop answers, and I do care about these scenarios. The "fine for you" bit was only out of respect for DeadMG's personal freedom of choice for his alarm clock app. :)

Comment: @DeadMG, if you're going to SpinWait it at least do it the right way with a SpinWait call (which will, where possible, use special cpu instructions that allow other things to happen on the core and reduce it's power consumption if not)

Answer (score 3):

Use `<` instead of `!=`.

In any case, that's a terrible way of waiting for a specific time.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an April Fools Joke?

Use `<` instead of `!=`.

Comment: It does look like an experiment to see what the answers are :-)

Comment: @Diego: @DeadMG is practically a C++ guru, I can't see him messing up something this simple.  So it must be a social experiment as you said.

Comment: OP may be a C++ guru, but he doesn't seem to have any rep on the C# tag, so it's not unreasonable for him to expect it to work.

Comment: @Gabe: OP is fully aware of numerical precision problems, which are no stranger to the C++ tag.

Answer (score 0):

I would switch that to being

```
while (System.DateTime.Now < new System.DateTime(2011, 05, 23, 22, 17, 0))
{
}
```

instead. Though I'd also be very wary of using a tight loop like that and would think that setting up a scheduled task or something would be much more effective.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to user the less than operator. <strike>I am a little surprised it misses the time by seconds, b</strike>But using equality for times is generally dangerous for this very *precise* reason (equality based on `Ticks`).

```
System.DateTime.Now < otherDateTime
```

It should be noted that this type of "busy waiting" is incredibly wasteful of the processor. As others are pointing out, use a timer, or at least sleep the thread so that the processor can do something else with its time.

Comment: I can't remember ever using equals on a non-generated `DateTime` (on both sides), which would explain why I never realized it actually compared the `Ticks`. Nice one.

Comment: @Ben: The *field* has that precision, but the *clock that fills in the field* only has accuracy to 1/64th of a second on most hardware.

Comment: @Eric: Which means only 64/1e7 of the possible `DateTime` values will ever be reached by the system clock, explaining the failure of the original code.  And some of those values probably go to other threads.