# How does one make an animation without being forced for it to end in windows forms?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, thread-safety

So here is the case. I have a winforms application which is a game. Naturally I want to put some animations like explosions when a bullet hits something. I've tried to achieve this by putting a .gif on my UI, waiting until the animation finishes and then deleting the `Control`, representing the .gif. I tried achieving that with this code:

```
public void AnimateAction(Actions Action, int PositionX, int PositionY)
        {
            Thread AnimationThread = null;
                AnimationThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => AnimateAction(Action, PositionX, PositionY, 1500)));
                AnimationThread.Start();
        }

private void AnimateAction(Actions Action, int PositionX, int PositionY, int AnimationDuration)
        {
                Control ActionAnimation = UiHandler.GetInstance().CreateActionItem(Action, PositionX, PositionY);
                this.Controls.Add(ActionAnimation);
                ActionAnimation.BringToFront();

                Thread.Sleep(AnimationDuration);
                this.Controls.Remove(ActionAnimation);

        }
```

Looks fine, doesn't it? Well.. it is not. Whenever I try to run this code I get an `InvalidOperationException` thrown, which tells me that I cannot access objects created on other threads. After doing some research on SO and other sources I've realized that I am trying to make unsafe call using threads, which is bad. The way to get around this is to call `Invoke()` method. However, this causes my animation to be run on the SAME thread that the main window is running, so while the animation thread is sleeping I am forced to wait for the animation to finish before I can see other actions being executed in the UI. Of course, I want to be able to move around etc. while my animation is being animated. How do I achieve this?

Comment: You need to run the animation on your UI thread but if you sleep there everything will freeze. Instead of sleeping should create the control and start a timer. When the timer has been running for the given duration, you can then remove the control. Extending Control with this shouldn't be too difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test this code but you have to check if the form itself requires an invoke. Invoke method assures that background thread is synchronized with the main thread. Plus I don't suggest you to use Thread.Sleep.

```
        public void AnimateAction(Actions Action, int PositionX, int PositionY)
        {
            Thread AnimationThread = null;
                AnimationThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => AnimateAction(Action, PositionX, PositionY, 1500)));
                AnimationThread.Start();
        }

        private void AnimateAction(Actions Action, int PositionX, int PositionY, int AnimationDuration)
        {
            if (form.Controls.InvokeRequired)
            {
                form.Controls.Invoke(new Action(AnimateAction), Action, PositionX, PositionY);
             }
             else
             {
                Control ActionAnimation = UiHandler.GetInstance().CreateActionItem(Action, PositionX, PositionY);
                form.Controls.Add(ActionAnimation);
                ActionAnimation.BringToFront();
                form.Controls.Remove(ActionAnimation);
               }


        }
```

Comment: This is the code I came up myself when looking for workaround for InvalidOperation exception. And the problem here is that when my animation is being executed I am forced to wait until it is animated. Also - I am up for suggestions, if you have a better way to achieve the animation functionality than Thread.Sleep() I am open for suggestions :)

Comment: @Buduls You can use a timer instead of Thread.Sleep check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707693/how-to-use-a-timer-to-replace-thread-sleep-in-an-azure-worker-role